# Issue with changing material of an object on keypress three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to apply colors stored in a array to my object when key pressed, But for some reason im able to get only first element of the array when keypressed. Kindly let me know if there is any other way of doing this.

i tried random color function but my requirement does not include applying colors randomly.

```
 var onKeyDown = function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 67) { // when 'c' is pressed
                                 var index=0;    

                                object.traverse( function( child ) { if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                                        if (child.material.name == "Leather")  {
                                           var colors = [0xff0000, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff]; // red, green and blue
                                            if(index == colors.length) index = 0;
                                            child.material.color.setHex(colors[index++]);
                                            child.material.needsUpdate=true;
                                            child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
                                            child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;

                                        }
                                        }});

                            } };
                                document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable 'index' is located in local scope of a function. So it will be initialized (var index=0;) every time as you push the C key.

You need only to move this variable outside the function and everything will be fine.

```
var index=0,
onKeyDown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 67) { // when 'c' is pressed
        object.traverse( function(child) { 
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                if (child.material.name == "Leather")  {
                    var colors = [0xff0000, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff]; // red, green and blue
                    if(index == colors.length) index = 0;
                    child.material.color.setHex(colors[index++]);
                    child.material.needsUpdate=true;
                    child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
                    child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
                }
             }
        });
    }
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, im also trying to call predefined variables like [White, Silicon] through an array, but when i call them in if condition on pressing "c" the changes are not reflecting. Any thoughts on this ?https://jsfiddle.net/304ub2t7/